# Descent datum on a functor restriction representability criterion

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, extension-field, tensor-products, affine-schemes

I am trying to understand the proof of the following theorem that can be found in [Affine Group Schemes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AGS.pdf) Chapter IV, Appendix.

[image]

Particularly, I do not understand why if $F'$ is the restriction of the functor $F$ to $k'$ algebras (via $k\to k'$) it is equipped with a descent datum.
I have done the following

[image]

This isomorphism is probably the descent datum I am looking for. However I am having problems trying to verify the cocycle conditions that can be found [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/023F) in Definition 35.3.1.

I thought about using the different maps $p_{ij}\colon k'\otimes_k k' \to k'\otimes_k k'\otimes_k k'$ that map an element $a\otimes b$ to the corresponding $ij$ entries. Then induce via $\varphi\colon A'\otimes_k k'\to k'\otimes_k A'$ (the isomorphism we found by Yoneda lemma)  the maps that lead to the cocyle condition. However, I am not able to see why the diagram in the definition for descent datum is commutative for this particular isomorphism.